# DCMTK storescp listener for many AE Titles

Tags: dcmtk

I want to use DCMTK's storescp (or perhaps dcmrecv) to receive DICOM files.  I want to give each potential sender a different AE_Title that they should send to.  Then I want to be able to identify the sender because I will see which AE_Title the DICOM was received on.  How to do this?
It looks like the dcmrecv with the -uca option might be the way, but I don't see how to tell which AE Title was used by the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Each DICOM Storage SCU identifies itself with an AE Title (so-called Calling AE Title), which is used by DCMTK's storescp to specify the value of the Source Application Entity Title (0002,0016) Attribute in the File Meta Information of the created DICOM files.

What you were asking for is the Called AE Title.

Comment: Except, as I understand it, the tag (0002,0016) is not transferred because its in the "metadata" and not the "regular data".  So, I don't know how to pull out (0002,0016) when I receive the file.

Comment: The File Meta Information (meta header) is created when storing a DICOM Data Set as a DICOM file, i.e. if the Data Set is transferred over network and the receiver (Storage SCP) stores the data as a DICOM file, the meta header is created. Some implementations, like e.g. DCMTK's storescp, also add the optional Source Application Entity Title (0002,0016) to the meta header. So, it depends on the software that you use whether the information is available in the meta header or not.